# Date field won't show with ItemStyle.xsl

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, item-styles

I'm pretty new user of SharePoint and i work with SharePoint 2010. I try to show the "StartDate" column of a page in my XSL template but it won't show. I put the column in the webpart configuration widget for my variable @DatePublication. I tested with the Title and Content column, they show well, but the date won't.

I try to put the Column "StartDate" into my @DatePublication variable.

First i set the variable name at @Date only, i guessed it can be a reserved word. I changed it to @DatePublication, wrapped it with "string()", i tried to convert the date with "ddwrt:FormatDate(@ArticleStartDate, 2057, 3)" from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx, didn't work.

What i did wrong? How can i show the Date in my template?

Thank you very much

```
<xsl:template name="ListeActualites" match="Row[@Style='ListeActualites']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
    <article class="contenu-bg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="image">
                <img class="image" src="" title="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-5 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-7 contenu">
                <div class="date"><xsl:value-of select="string(@DatePublication)"/></div>
                <h2><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></a></h2>
                <p><xsl:value-of select="substring(@Contenu,0,200)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />...</p>
                <div class="tags"><xsl:value-of select="@Sujet" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact solution to your problem. But have you tried just writing @DatePublication instead of wrapping it in string(@DatePublication)?

Here is a good link if you need to find some ways to format the date:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx

Comment: I tried it and re-tried it, it doesn't work :(